# MYSQL "Like" query for forward and reverse word orders

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL Table that contains person name with each row has a value:

- John Smith
- Smith John
- Smith Warren John,
- John
- Smith

If i were to search "John Smith" using regular LIKE "%John Smith%", those with "John Smith" name will show, but other row will not show. I want "Smith John" and "Smith Warren John" to appear as well in my query, because they has both JOHN and SMITH. how do I achieve this? or should i split and make all the possible combination?

=> LIKE "%John Smith%" or LIKE "%Smith John%"

Comment: `LIKE '%John%' AND LIKE '%Smith%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Smith Warren John"

Yes, for your current data structure you should
split and make all possible combinations,
such as "SELECT ... name LIKE '%John%Smith%' OR name LIKE '%Smith%John%'".
@fusion3k helpfully observes that we can refactor that to be simpler:

```
SELECT ... name LIKE '%John%' AND name LIKE '%Smith%'
```

Do consider changing your on-disk data structure.
I assume the table contains "many" rows,
so indexing matters.
Please understand that leading `%` wildcard
tends to disable indexes, forcing scanning behavior
instead.
Pay attention to the
[EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html)
query plan.
Often a pair of indexed queries will
take less time than a single tablescan.

Consider issuing a single query for `'%Smith%'`
and then have your script filter the rows
that come back, looking for additional string matches.

It might be worth your while to have a script
take a pass over all rows and UPDATE to populate
a new column that has a modified name spelling,
for example split on blanks to produce the reversed
name. Or you might even choose to store duplicate
copies of the name, including reversed, as single string.
Alphabetizing words within a string can simplify queries.
Other normalization, such as downcasing the name,
may also prove helpful.
Storing an "extra" leading blank, and a trailing one,
can make it easier to author some wildcard queries.

---

Mysql offers
[regex support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html)
via the `REGEXP` / `RLIKE` keywords.

---

Consider using an on-disk index that is tailored to
[full text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html).

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for your reply. i will look into those links. Much appreciated